# JavaFX Chart is not completely cleared

Tags: javafx

```java
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Test extends VBox {
    public AreaChart<Number, Number> chart = new AreaChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    public XYChart.Series<Number, Number> chartSeries = new XYChart.Series<>();

    public Test() {
        this.chart.setAnimated(false);
        this.chart.getData().addAll(this.chartSeries);

        super.getChildren().add(this.chart);
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.chartSeries.getData().clear();
    }
}

some for loops {
    test.infectedPeopleSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(i, j));
}

after click on button {
    test.clear();
}
```

I am displaying some data in chart in real time, it works.

Then I'd like to clear the chart and run the displaying again.

But after the clearing, the chart is not completely cleared.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V6mv.png)

What do I do wrong?

P.S. I do have set animation to false.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are only clearing the timeseries. There could be more items on the chart.

You could try

```
chart.getData().clear();
```